# Run query against another procedure that returns a cursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure that that has an OUT sys_refcursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_detail_data(RC1            IN OUT sys_REFCURSOR)
IS ...
```

Now in another a procedure, I'm trying to calculate some statistics against the output of that procedure so I can insert them into a table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE load_stats
AS
cur_detail  SYS_REFcursor;

BEGIN
  -- Load the data from the "get_detail_data" procedure
  get_detail_data(cur_detail);

  -- Now lets calculate some stats against that detail data and insert
  insert into stats_table (
    select
      id_number, sum(amount)
    from table(cur_detail) -- obviously this is not valid
  )

END;
```

How can I run a query against a sys_refcursor dataset and insert those results into another table?

Answer (score 0):

You can start fetching from an open cursor like this:

```
  LOOP  -- Fetches 2 columns into variables
    FETCH cur_detail INTO v_id_number, v_amount;
    EXIT WHEN cv%NOTFOUND;
    [... insert etc ...]
  END LOOP;
```

I'd suggest to do aggregation within the cursor, otherwise you need to order by id_number and aggregate within the loop, breaking by id_number.